# How to update product image positions with csv?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, database-update

i have bulk number of product with images whose `Base Image` needs to be changed. I have `SKU` file in a `CSV` format.

How can I update the `Base Image` of a product, any `CSV` or db query for this ?

Comment: after export product list update using _media_position column value.

Comment: its help me : http://www.onlinecode.org/blog/2016/12/19/magento-update-product-image/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Magmi` to upload bulk no.of products,you can update the product details by `CSV`.
For this,you have to add the `image` column where you have to give the product image url. You can also add or update your small image or thumbnail image by adding `small_image` and `thumbnail` columns

Comment: its help me : http://www.onlinecode.org/blog/2016/12/19/magento-update-product-image/